# v-navigation-drawer from vuetify examples doesn't work on my code

Tags: vuetify.js

Using vuetify example source below:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/#expand-on-hover

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhaqv.png)
[when the mouse hover, drawer opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTbpg.png)

My code is like this (same as the example):

```html
 <div class="ma-12 pa-12">
    <v-card>
      <v-navigation-drawer
        permanent
        expand-on-hover
      >
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item class="px-2">
            <v-list-item-avatar>
              <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/85.jpg"></v-img>
            </v-list-item-avatar>
          </v-list-item>

          <v-list-item link>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title class="text-h6">
                Sandra Adams
              </v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-subtitle>sandra_a88@gmail.com</v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-list
          nav
          dense
        >
          <v-list-item link>
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-folder</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>My Files</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item link>
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-account-multiple</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Shared with me</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item link>
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-star</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Starred</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-card>
  </div>
```

I expected to open drawer when mouse-hover. but i get this preview below:
[it's already opend! and it looks weired somehow..][3]

my vue version is 3.
and i don't know why.. if i copy & paste the examples from vuetify website, it doesn't work properly (text-field properties like outline, dense.. don't apply too T_T)

Comment: Vuetify 3 documentation is at https://next.vuetifyjs.com/

Comment: Thank you for your advice. it was Vuetify 3 version crash problem.